# Is it right the usage of the word "certainly" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I was discussing with a friend about possibilities and he told me:

```
When you have more certainly you should use "will" instead of "may",
```

but I am not sure if the word "certainly" can be used like this, I would like to appreciate any explanation of its usage, I got confuse since I believe that this word can be used in many ways, I am not sure if it is a verb or an adjective.

Comment: You're probably using the wrong word. Almost certainly (though I can't say with absolute certainty) you don't want the adverb ***certainly*** at all - you should be using the noun ***certainty***.

Comment: Yes I agree maybe I got confuse since both sounds very similar.

Comment: It depends on what you *mean*. Your exact text as written above (putting aside pedantic matters like whether it should any commas) could validly be interpreted as meaning ***It is certainly true that** when you have more you should use [blah blah]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the *noun* you are thinking of in your sentence is

> **certainty**

which is a measure of the probability that something will happen

> When something happens with certainty, it has a probability of 1.0
>
> **certainly**

is the *adverb* to describe certainty.

> If *something* has **certainty**, it will **certainly** happen.